# Why are my dimensions not updating on resize when using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, framer-motion

My dimensions are not updating whenever the window is resized. In the code below you can see the window.innerHeight is updated, but the dimensions are not. I am probably missing something but I have not figured it out yet.

```
// Navbar.components.ts:

export const sidebar = () => {
    let height;
    let width;

    if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
        height = window.innerHeight
        width = window.innerWidth
    }

    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
        windowHeight: height,
        windowWidth: width,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
            setDimensions({
                windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
                windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            });
            // Logging window.innerHeight gives the current height,
            // Logging dimensions.windowHeight gives the initial height
            console.log(window.innerHeight, " . ", dimensions.windowHeight)
        }, 100);

        window.addEventListener(`resize`, debouncedHandleResize)
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize)

    }, [])

    return {
        open: () => ({
            clipPath: `circle(${dimensions.windowHeight * 2 + 200}px at 40px 40px)`,
            transition: {
                type: "spring",
                stiffness: 20,
                restDelta: 2
            }
        }),
        closed: () => ({
            clipPath: `circle(30px at ${300 - 40}px ${dimensions.windowHeight - 45}px)`,
            transition: {
                delay: 0.2,
                type: "spring",
                stiffness: 400,
                damping: 40
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And I use the sidebar like this:

```
// Navbar.tsx

const Navbar: React.FC<NavbarProps> = () => {
  ...
  
  return {
      ...
      <MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar()} />
      ...
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the logs that are returned when resizing the window:

[image: Logs that are returned]

**Update 1**

@sygmus1897

Code changed to this:

```
// Navbar.tsx: 

const Navbar: React.FC<NavbarProps> = () => {

  const [windowWidth, windowHeight] = getDimensions();
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [windowWidth, windowHeight])

  return (
     ...
     <MobileNavWrapper
        initial={false}
        animate={menuIsOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
        custom={height}
        ref={ref}
        menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      >
        <MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar} custom={windowHeight} />
        <MobileNav menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
        <MenuToggle toggle={() => toggleMenu()} />
      </MobileNavWrapper>
   )
}
```

```
// getDimensions()
export const getDimensions = () => {
    const [dimension, setDimension] = useState([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            setDimension([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {
                setDimension([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
            })
        }
    }, []);
    
    return dimension;

};
```

```
// Navbar.components.ts

export const sidebar = {
    open: (height) => ({
        clipPath: `circle(${height + 200}px at 40px 40px)`,
        transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 20,
            restDelta: 2
        }
    }),
    closed: (height) => ({
        clipPath: `circle(30px at ${300 - 60}px ${height - 65}px)`,
        transition: {
            delay: 0.2,
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 400,
            damping: 40
        }
    })
}
```

The issue remains where resizing the window does not affect the clipPath position of the circle. To illustrate the issue visually, the hamburger is supposed to be inside the green circle: [image: Issue]

Comment: Setting state is asynhronous. It is not reflecting immediately, but is actually updating the state. Next render cycle would have the updated values

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when looking at the console it keeps returning the same initial height (initial height being window.innerHeight on the first render). Some examples of the logs I'm getting are: 300 ' . ' 602, 326 ' . ' 602, 382 ' . ' 602.

Comment: Looks like a case of stale state. A closure has been made on the old values. Also your event listener is set once and is never removed and reattached(just pointing out). Try adding `}, [dimensions])` to the dep array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this thread: [Framer Motion - stale custom value - changing the custom value doesn't trigger an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027738/framer-motion-stale-custom-value-changing-the-custom-value-doesnt-trigger-a/) I found that the issue I'm having is a bug in framer-motion. To resolve this issue, add a key value to the motion component that's having issues re-rendering. This makes sure React re-renders the component.

In my case all I had to do was this:

```
<MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar} custom={windowHeight} key={key} />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom hook to listen to window resize.

You can modify solution from this link as per you requirement [Custom hook for window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588340/custom-hook-for-window-resize)

By using useState instead of ref, updating it on resize and returning the values to your main component

Here's an example:

```
export default function useWindowResize() {
    const [dimension, setDimension] = useState([0, 0]);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            setDimension([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {
                setDimension([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
            })
        }
    }, []);
    
    return dimension;
}
```

and inside your main component use it like this:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
    const [width, height] = useWindowResize();
    useEffect(()=>{
        // your operations
    }, [width, height])
}
```

Your component will update every time the dimensions are changed. And you will get the updated width and height

EDIT:

Framer-motion provides a way to dynamically set variant's properties(for detailed guide refer to this [Dynamically Update Variant](https://thewebdev.info/2020/10/24/framer-motion%E2%80%8A-%E2%80%8Adynamic-variants-and-animation-controls/)) :-

```
// Navbar.tsx: 

const Navbar: React.FC<NavbarProps> = () => {
  return (
     ...
     <MobileNavWrapper
        initial={false}
        custom={window.innerWidth} // custom={window.innerHeight} if variable depends on Height
        animate={menuIsOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
        custom={height}
        ref={ref}
        menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      >
        <MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar} />
        <MobileNav menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
        <MenuToggle toggle={() => toggleMenu()} />
      </MobileNavWrapper>
   )
}
```

```
// Navbar.components.ts

export const sidebar = {
    open: (width) => ({ 
        clipPath: `circle(${width+ 200}px at 40px 40px)`,
        transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 20,
            restDelta: 2
        }
    }),
    closed: (width) => ({
        clipPath: `circle(30px at ${300 - 60}px ${width- 65}px)`,
        transition: {
            delay: 0.2,
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 400,
            damping: 40
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice explanation. I'm just curious, how could I use the height to send it to a child like so: ```<MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar(height)} />``` ?

Comment: @LarsvanderNiet By using the custom hook inside the sidebar component itself you should be able directly access the height's value. But if you want to pass it via parent component using `<MobileNavBackground variants={sidebar(height)} />` with `export const sidebar = (height) => { ...`  should do the trick

Comment: I have tried that and it kind of worked. When logging height within the sidebar function it returns the correct height, but using the height in the return statement (for creating a circle using framer-motion clipPath), it keeps returning the initial height.

Comment: Could this have to do with framer-motion using the initial values and storing them somehow?

Comment: @LarsvanderNiet Yeah looks like It is using the initial values because it has already returned those 'open' and 'close' variant object with value it got initially. I think you are using those variants by calling them (like: open() and close()) correct?

Comment: Yes, I use them like this: ```animate={menuIsOpen ? "open" : "closed"}```. It is a framer-motion specific thing I guess

Comment: @LarsvanderNiet Check this out [link](https://thewebdev.info/2020/10/24/framer-motion%E2%80%8A-%E2%80%8Adynamic-variants-and-animation-controls/) I don't think you will even need a custom hook for that. change your `open: ()=>` to `open: (width)=>` and use that in your variant object and pass `custom={window.innerWidth}` on the motion component along with animate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237484/discussion-between-sygmus1897-and-lars-van-der-niet).